# UNetbootin not detecting mounted USB?

Tags: usb-creator

UNetbootin is not detecting a mounted USB, the image below shows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then remount your USB stick, if needed manually using `mount -o remount /dev/sdb1`. (And disable any hardware based write protection switch)

Comment: @the_Seppi `mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Comment: Try replugging the stick. If you wiped it before, you may have to recreate its partition table (using GParted or GNU Parted)

Comment: @the_Seppi Updated! Also tried replugging, still not working.

Comment: Close UnetBootin, open GParted, umount the stick partition, create a new msdos partition table on the stick, create a FAT32 partition on the stick, mount it by replugging and start UnetBootin. If this doesn't help, I'm clueless, too. Also ensure you are running UnetBootin as root.

Comment: @the_Seppi UnetBootin doesn't need the root privileges

Comment: @KarlMorrison couple of suggestions:1)  replug the stick, check `lsblk` to find what's your usb's device name again, just in case, but most likely it didnt change 2) run `sudo mount -o uid=1000 /dev/sdb1 /mnt` ; your stick now should be mounted with write/read permissions to  your username. Alternatively , try running it with `-o umask 0000`.  The message you saw is probably because you didn't specify where to mount the stick ( I put /mnt there )

Comment: let me know if this helps

Comment: Format the usb drive as fat32 file system solve this issue.

Comment: I can confirm this bug also for **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**. However, in my case `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` effectively solved the problem. :-)

Answer (score 14):

Just mount your drive:

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Comment: Result: "Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
"

Answer (score 11):

original answer from maxter (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=165389)

> from command line type:
>
> ```
> sudo unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdX
> ```
>
> unetbootin GUI will open with the selected drive already setted, also
>   if it is ntfs formatted.

Comment: Also I had to install `p7zip-full` as unetbootin was complaining about its absence

Comment: Well, there's something that should be in the f***ing man(1) page!

Comment: This did the trick for me. However I had to add the partition number in the device name: `targetdrive=/dev/sdc1` and I had to manually mount the USB stick (for some reason, just inserting it didn't do it) with `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mountpoint` before calling unetbootin.

Comment: **Note that your USB partition has to be big enough and *empty***, as any old partitions from `dd`ing ISOs to it, may be too small, and `unetbootin` will complain (and fail to write everything, if you ignore that and the new contents happen to be to big).

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me

1. Delete partition in `sdb1` in Gparted.
2. Reformat.
3. In terminal, type `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`.
4. Run UNetbootin as normal.

Comment: unetbootin could not detect a `/dev/sdb1` `dd`'ed with a Debian iso.  I created a VFAT filesystem on top (`mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1`) and then it was found. The resulting Debian install disk managed to boot on my old Thinkpad X201—unlike the regular `dd` method.

Comment: Thanks @melissa_boiko, same problem here. Old netbook won't boot from a `dd`'d USB stick, `unetbootin` doesn't recognize the stick while it has the ISO filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (worked well in my case):

1. (while Unetbootin is open and iso file mounted)
2. open GParted, go to GParted menu, select Devices and tick the path to your USB (/dev/sdb1)
3. Unetbootin should now recognize your USB drive and proceed with copying.
4. (you will perhaps need to eject and reinsert your USB before)

Comment: Don't know why, but this worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the sequence you followed is as follows; your stick is formatted to contain a FAT32 file system.

1. You may have inserted the stick, selected your ISO, Unetbootin has detected your stick which reflects the screenshot of Unetbootin.
2. However, in the second step, you may have unmounted the stick manually or otherwise, but UNetbootim may not have refreshed
3. Now when you try to create the bootable USB, it cannot find where the stick is mounted because it has been unmounted.

Typically, I have noticed that the following steps work:

- Remove the bootable stick from the USB socket
- Launch Unetbootin, it would not show anything in the last row of fields, it would be empty.
- Now plug in the USB stick, it should detect and the contents will be automatically filled including the mount point
- Now proceed to create the bootable USB

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I am using Linux (Fedora) and I was formating the USB drive with the aplication "Disks" (default with this distro) and UNetBootin did not find the drive.
I fixed the issue by reformating the USB using GParted. Now it is visible on UNetBootin. I don't know why, maybe some partition flag?

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting all files from my USB (even hidden ones, found with `ctrl+h`)** helped Unetbootin find it in my case, I didn't even have to reboot Unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.

insert USB drive, unmounting the USB via file explorer and mounting manually in /mnt did the trick for me.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdbx /mnt    
sudo unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdbX
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1289951)